# City and Municipality

Tags: contacts

I am testing with CIVICRM in Spain and I don`t know the location of the information of Cities and Municipaly for test importing Contacts. Can you help me. I test with Wordpress.
Thanks

Andreu

Comment: For test data, you can enter any real or artificial cities - but I'm probably not understanding what you need.  Can you describe what you have and what is missing?

Comment: In the process of import conytact, list this errors                                                                     1,"Invalid value for field(s) : El valor de entrada del municipio no aparece en la tabla de municipios: El valor del municipio no parece ser v√°lido. No coincide con ning√∫n valor en la tabla de los municipios de CiviCRM.","Taxi + Vol","930","Si","DONATO CARNER","ESTHER","37607877-W","ESTHER@gmail.com","682775887","06-oct-43","Avda. Sarri√†, 42, 3er, 1a.","Barcelona","08029","Les Corts","","11","2019","Josep Anton Perez","JAP","","D"

Comment: Sounds like you assigned a text field to one of civicrm's prefilled geo fields. All of civicrm's geo data are in the database. Maybe you should manually add some contacts in the gui with all relevant data, export them and use the export csv as template for your imports.